# Call an external URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to call an external URL and check the status in laravel 5.4.

I've looked at using Guzzle:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
....

$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('some-external-url');
dd($res->getBody());
```

But with dusk testing and other new things in 5.4, is there a better method now? Also guzzle doesnt appear to be a dependency anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Curl allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of servers with many different types of protocols. libcurl currently supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension), HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password authentication.

There are N Number of Curl Libraries for Laravel

First is [anlutro/php-curl](https://github.com/anlutro/php-curl) .

Second is [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl)

Comment: Guzzle is just a wrapper for curl no?

Comment: Yea You are right. But if you're strictly concerned about the protocol's peculiarities Curl is Best.